# HighCharts displays incorrect time on x-axis

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

I have datetime values in an array which are converted from ISO to milliseconds. E.g. 2015-05-07T06:08:54.430062Z , on converting "06:08:54.430062" to milliseconds, I get something like this 1430978934438.

Such values when plotted on x-axis don't give me back my original value like "06:08:54.430062", I get some other converted value on the x-axis such as 11:20:00. How can I get to show my original value or approximately the same value?

Comment: Can you make a jsFiddle with your problem please ?

Comment: You can use this : http://jsfiddle.net/gh7kqkjf/ this one has converted ISO values though.

Comment: If you look at what those timestamp values are, removing the 'useUTC:false' option gives the expected date/time.

Comment: Thanks @jibriggs. I am pretty new to HighCharts, so wasn't aware of this option. I think the downvote was bit harsh. Anyway